# Single sign on with SQL Server? Security and performance

Tags: sql-server, authentication, single-sign-on

I'm working on a website (asp.net c# with SQL Server) and the client is asking for SSO solution. I'm looking to use one shortest implementation where we can create sub-domains for different modules and install/deploy on same or different servers but all of these module/application uses same SQL Server and session is also maintained and shared by SQL Server. However the client is concerned about the performance/scalability and security therefore I would like your advise if you have already worked on such projects and if you would recommend me this solution or anything else.

thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Keep your single sign on information in LDAP.  It's definitely the most standardized way to store user information and access.  It's really just a database but if scalability and performance are concerns this is your best bet.